# How can I beat Zone 48 in Besiege?

Tags: besiege

I'm having difficulty completing *Zone 48: Mesa Outpost* on the Isle of Krolmar in the game ***Besiege***. The victory condition is presented as "Destroy the Cannons", but the level is not completing even after the cannons appear destroyed.

Are there additional undisclosed criteria, such as killing all enemies? Is the amount of damage I have dealt to the cannons insufficient for them to be counted as "destroyed"? Have I done something else wrong? Here are photos of the cannons, which seem pretty destroyed to me...

[image: Cannon 1]

[image: Cannon 2]

[image: Cannon 3]

[image: Cannon 4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would rather not cheat, it does in fact look like you just have to kill everyone.

But...

I made this which should make the level easier. It is cheatsy but it gets the job done if you're fed up with it.

https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=2001761875